# ParseError 1:1 Using Tensorflow with Bazel

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

#### System information

Running Python 3.6.4 on Windows

#### Describe the problem

I'm trying to run Tensorflow's lm_1b on sample mode, by inputting:

`$ bazel-bin/lm_1b/lm_1b_eval --mode sample --prefix "I love that I"  --pbtxt data/vocab-2016-09-10.txt --vocab_file data/vocab-2016-09-10.txt --ckpt 'data/ckpt-*'`

But I get the error:

`google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 1:1 : Expected identifier or number, got <.`

Any help would really be appreciated

#### Source code / logs

`Recovering graph.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\?\C:\Users\snmsa\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_9sq54ngc\runfiles\__main__\lm_1b\lm_1b_eval.py", line 308, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "\\?\C:\Users\snmsa\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_9sq54ngc\runfiles\__main__\lm_1b\lm_1b_eval.py", line 298, in main
    _SampleModel(FLAGS.prefix, vocab)
  File "\\?\C:\Users\snmsa\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_9sq54ngc\runfiles\__main__\lm_1b\lm_1b_eval.py", line 174, in _SampleModel
    sess, t = _LoadModel(FLAGS.pbtxt, FLAGS.ckpt)
  File "\\?\C:\Users\snmsa\AppData\Local\Temp\Bazel.runfiles_9sq54ngc\runfiles\__main__\lm_1b\lm_1b_eval.py", line 89, in _LoadModel
    text_format.Merge(s, gd)
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 533, in Merge
    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 587, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 620, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 635, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 679, in _MergeField
    name = tokenizer.ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber()
  File "C:\Users\snmsa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.py", line 1152, in ConsumeIdentifierOrNumber
    raise self.ParseError('Expected identifier or number, got %s.' % result)
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 1:1 : Expected identifier or number, got <.`

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is wrong. It should be:

```
bazel-bin/lm_1b/lm_1b_eval --mode sample \
                           --prefix "I love that I" \
                           --pbtxt data/graph-2016-09-10.pbtxt \
                           ...
```

You are passing a vocabulary file `--pbtxt data/vocab-2016-09-10.txt` where a serialized GraphDef file is expected.